# Error message "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" on Jena Fuseki

Tags: json, sparql, jena

I have to use apache [jena-fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/getting_started/index.html), an application web to query an [RDF file](https://www.w3.org/RDF/) write in XML language. When I load the file it show me an error message about the function JSON.parse. I check the document and it is correct, I tried with a RDF Validator([link](https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/)) and it doesn't give me any problem.

Any idea why I can't load the file?

[JSON Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lLeL.jpg)

This is the file code:

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:archaeo="http://www.ics.forth.gr/isl/CRMext/CRMarchaeo.rdfs/"
  xmlns:crm="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/"
  xmlns:sci="http://www.ics.forth.gr/isl/CRMext/CRMsci.rdfs/"
  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
  xmlns:crmdig="http://www.ics.forth.gr/isl/CRMext/CRMdig.rdfs/"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <crm:E4_Period rdf:about="http://archaeositarproject.it/st_named_year_range_#59">
    <crm:P4_has_time-span>
      <crm:E52_Time-Span>
        <crm:P82b_end_of_the_end rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-961</crm:P82b_end_of_the_end>
        <crm:P81b_begin_of_the_end rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-961</crm:P81b_begin_of_the_end>
        <crm:P81a_end_of_the_begin rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-1200</crm:P81a_end_of_the_begin>
        <crm:P82a_begin_of_the_begin rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-1200</crm:P82a_begin_of_the_begin>
      </crm:E52_Time-Span>
    </crm:P4_has_time-span>
    <crm:P1_is_identified_by>
      <crm:E49_Time_Appellation>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Età del Bronzo Finale</rdfs:label>
      </crm:E49_Time_Appellation>
    </crm:P1_is_identified_by>
  </crm:E4_Period>
  <crm:E4_Period rdf:about="http://archaeositarproject.it/st_named_year_range_#58">
    <crm:P4_has_time-span>
      <crm:E52_Time-Span>
        <crm:P82b_end_of_the_end rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-1201</crm:P82b_end_of_the_end>
        <crm:P81b_begin_of_the_end rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-1201</crm:P81b_begin_of_the_end>
        <crm:P81a_end_of_the_begin rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-1250</crm:P81a_end_of_the_begin>
        <crm:P82a_begin_of_the_begin rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gYear">-1250</crm:P82a_begin_of_the_begin>
      </crm:E52_Time-Span>
    </crm:P4_has_time-span>
    <crm:P1_is_identified_by>
      <crm:E49_Time_Appellation>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Età del Bronzo Recente, fase II</rdfs:label>
      </crm:E49_Time_Appellation>
    </crm:P1_is_identified_by>
  </crm:E4_Period>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Which Fuseki version do you use?

Comment: Fuseki version 3.5.0 @AKSW

Comment: Try Fuseki version 3.6.0 (This looks like issue JENA-1420, fixed in 3.6.0)

Comment: Thanks, now it work. Sorry but I had't  seen the new version

Comment: Great - added as an answer for the record.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Apache Jena Fuseki v3.5.0 and is fixed in v3.6.0.